# Appending to jquery dialog apparent bug -- any workarounds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When appending to a jquery dialog, it automatically resizes the dialog to fit the new content.

That's great.

After moving the dialog, this functionality breaks.

That sucks.

As you can see in this fiddle, the dialog works great UNTIL you move it.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
   resizable: true,
    autoOpen: true,     
});


window.setInterval(function(){
  $("#innerdiv").append("<br>Append!");
}, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8dtd8bg/

Anyway to work around this apparent bug in jquery?

Comment: Fancy bug :-) Maybe report it to jquery?

Comment: @Neal alright, will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I was using an old version of Jquery UI. Works now :P

https://jsfiddle.net/f8dtd8bg/1/

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
 resizable: true,
 autoOpen: true, 
});

window.setInterval(function(){
  $("#innerdiv").append("<br>Append!");
}, 2000);
```